# Can't use a third setState. Error: Too many re-renders

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to set an initial state to my Hook, and I have a clickable that when clicked changes the state to Decreasing and Increasing, this part is working fine. The problem is when I try to define the initial state my code crashes and says that are `Too Many re-renders. React limits the numbers of renders to produce an infinite loop.`

```
    const [measures, setMeasures] = useState([]);
    const [duration, setDuration] = useState([]);
    const [word, setWord] = useState('Increasing')

    useEffect(() => {
        api.get('measures').then(res => {
            setMeasures(res.data.measures);
            // let a = res.data.measures
        });
    }, []);
    
    const total = measures.map((duration) => {
        return parseFloat(duration.duration);
    });

    setDuration(total) <<<<<HERE IS CRASHING 

    const action = () => {
        if (word === 'Increasing') {
            setWord('Decreasing');

            const increasing = () => {
                let organiseIncrease = total.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return (b - a)
                });
                setDuration(organiseIncrease);
            };
            increasing()
        } else {
            setWord('Increasing');

            const decreasing = () => {
                let organiseDecreasing = total.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return(a - b)
                });
                setDuration(organiseDecreasing)
            };
            decreasing()
        }  
    }
```

total returns numbers like [15, 12, 50];
I just want to render this array automatically when I enter the page and then click the button to organise to a increasing/decreasing order. I tried to change de hook to:

```
const [duration, setDuration] = useState([total]);
```

But gives me: [undefined].
I tough about wrap all in a function and use Async/Await to fill the hook but I don't know if it'll work.
Any clue how can I fix this code?

Comment: You are updating the state and using useEffect hook togather caused render loop.

Comment: Move setting the duration inside your useEffect hook; you're setting inside the main function i.e. during a render, which triggers a re-render, etc, etc, -> infinite loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is exactly on the place where you have mentioned, which is here:

```
setDuration(total) <<<<<HERE IS CRASHING
```

here you are updating the state which is in main function and this is not wrapped inside a `useEffect()` or some `event handler function`. On every render you update the state and every update on state triggers re-render and this goes on and on.

Its just like:

```
A -> B -> A  // Which creates an infinite loop
```

**Solution:**

Put this under the `useEffect()` like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...
  setDuration(total);
  ...
}, []);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I called total inside the useEffect. Then on my function I called the array hook and organised in Increase and Decrease. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you are updating the `State` you are making the code re-render
you can update you code with the below:

```
useEffect(() => {
        api.get('measures').then(res => {
            setMeasures(res.data.measures);
            // let a = res.data.measures
             const total = res.data.measures.map((duration) => {
                  return parseFloat(duration.duration);
              });

              setDuration(total); 

        });
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the issue because the setDuration after the mapping measures will be executed every time in the render cycle of react. as it is declared in the app means the code executed when a re-render occures.

Have a try by making a bit of change in the code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    api.get('measures').then(res => {
        setMeasures(res.data.measures);
        // let a = res.data.measures
        setDuration(res.data.measures.map((duration) => parseFloat(duration.duration)));
}, []);
```